# Getting Union, Intersection, or Difference of Sets in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, set, intersection, unions

I have a couple questions about how to use C++ sets (std::set)

1. Is there a way to get the union, intersection, or difference of two C++ sets? (It's pretty easy to write my own functionto do that but I wanted to know if there was a built in function for it)
2. Can C++ sets be used as keys in a map?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the [`set_difference()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference), [`set_union()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union), [`set_intersection()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) and [`set_symmetric_difference()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_symmetric_difference) functions.

Sets and maps support any key type that can compare.  By default this means the type has `operator<()` defined, but you can provide your own comparator. C++ sets don't have `operator<()` defined and therefore can't be used as keys unless you provide your own comparator.

Comment: And you probably don't want to provide your own comparator unless you can find a way to figure out which set is "less than" the other quickly -- i.e. *without* reading all of its members, which could get very slow for a large set.

Answer (score 3):

Anything can be used as a key in a map as long as you provide a class or function that can compare them. [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/map/) is an example.