# SetUnion: set<int> × set<int> → set<int>

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a SetUnion function that takes two `set<int>` elements and unions them.

`SetUnion: set<int> × set<int> → set<int>`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What gives? Who just decrements without explanation?

Comment: I guess because you don't show what you've tried yet. What about [`set_union`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union)?

Comment: Try to do it with your own hands, and come back when you have a real and specific problem.

Comment: What is your question?  Perhaps you could explain why you don't want to use the `set_union` function that you already have.

Comment: Well, that's the thing, I don't know how to access data in the set, so if I have a while loop for the user pop values into the set (something I don't know how to do also), then how am I to access them? I thought about just having them copied into a vector because I thought it'd be easier that way.

Comment: You can still [edit] your question to include that information and the question you want to ask.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Union, Intersection, or Difference of Sets in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736017/getting-union-intersection-or-difference-of-sets-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are dealing with `std::set`, a union can be built by simply adding elements of the two sets together, like this:

```
set<int> a {1,2,3,4};
set<int> b {3,4,5,6};
// Copy the first set
set<int> u(a);
// Add elements of the second set to the copy to get a union
u.insert(b.begin(), b.end());
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/l9Cq99).

Answer (score 1):

This function already exists within the standard library, see [std::set_union](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union), which you can use as follows:

```
std::vector<int> vec1 = {1, 2, 4}, vec2 = {5, 4, 2}, vecUnion;

std::set_union( vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), std::back_inserter(vecUnion) );

for( auto i : vecUnion )
{
     std::cout << i << ", " std::endl;
}
```

Which will print out the following:

```
1, 2, 4, 5,
```